# Different fit comparing lm( ) and lmList( ). Why?

Tags: r, linear-regression, lm

Given this dataframe called 'data1':

```
     a   b    c   
    60  7.42  1   
    52 35.83  1   
    42 32.75  1   
    94 30.50  1   
    84 52.08  1   
    70 30.25  1  
    59 41.75  1   
   103 42.50  1  
    49 30.67  1   
    50 37.33  1   
    54 12.25  2   
    73 36.16  2   
    79  3.33  2  
    89  4.50  2   
   110 53.35  2  
    84 10.50  2   
    64 36.67  2   
    74  7.42  2   
    76  5.67  2  
    75 58.08  2  
    70 40.42  3   
    94 34.08  3   
    73 35.33  3   
    51  5.25  3   
    70 19.92  3   
    88 52.00  3   
    52  8.42  3   
    87 13.00  3   
   114 65.25  3  
    86 43.42  3
```

I want to do a linear regression in R using the lm() function. I want to fit a regression for each 'c' level. So, I can use lmList(), or instead lm() separately for each level of c.

Using lmList(), I obtain:

```
summary(fit1 <- (lmList(a ~ b | c, data=data1)))

Call:
  Model: a ~ b | c 
   Data: data1 

Coefficients:
   (Intercept) 
      Estimate Std. Error  t value     Pr(>|t|)
1     48.40474  17.190453 2.815792 9.571251e-03
2     74.06143   7.995761 9.262587 2.146984e-09
3     54.03792  10.418448 5.186753 2.591707e-05
   b 
       Estimate Std. Error  t value   Pr(>|t|)
1     0.5246647  0.4795047 1.094180 0.28473633
2     0.1640226  0.2628905 0.623920 0.53856582
3     0.7714555  0.2829830 2.726155 0.01177752

Residual standard error: 16.74138 on 24 degrees of freedom
```

However, if I use lm() for each group (e.g., c=3):

```
data1_3 <- subset(data1,c==3)

summary(fit2 <- lm(a ~ b, data=data1_3))

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-15.220  -7.992  -3.844   7.367  22.933 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  54.0379     7.8395   6.893 0.000125 ***
b             0.7715     0.2129   3.623 0.006753 **
```

So, p-value of the group (c=3) is 0.01 with lmList(), but 0.006 with lm().
Why this difference?

Comment: The standard error computed by `lmList` is higher. Check the help file for any explanation about corrections that it makes (I suspect it uses data from all 3 chunks).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the documentation:

> pool:  an optional logical value indicating whether a pooled estimate
>   of the residual standard error should be used in calculations of
>   standard deviations or standard errors for summaries.

```
library(nlme)
summary(fit1 <- (lmList(a ~ b | c, data=DF, pool=FALSE)))
Call:
  Model: a ~ b | c 
   Data: DF 

Coefficients:
#   (Intercept) 
#  Estimate Std. Error   t value     Pr(>|t|)
#1 48.40474  21.656460  2.235118 5.584928e-02
#2 74.06143   7.357469 10.066157 8.080255e-06
#3 54.03792   7.839491  6.893039 1.254064e-04
#   b 
#   Estimate Std. Error   t value    Pr(>|t|)
#1 0.5246647  0.6040780 0.8685380 0.410397519
#2 0.1640226  0.2419042 0.6780478 0.516869219
#3 0.7714555  0.2129341 3.6229776 0.006753388
```